# Python import module (xlwt) from archive

Tags: python, module, package, archive, xlwt

Let's say Tight Ars & Co. is a company with incredibly tight security policies, and lets assume I work for this company.  Assume they've one task that requires a python script to write to excel files, and I find this incredibly wonderful library called xlwt. Now my script is able to write to excel files, everything is wonderful and the sun is shining, I release the code, and suddenly I'm asked what is this thingamajig setup.py, why should we run it? wait, we'll not even run it, we want the environment to be clean from third party code etc etc, since I'm unaware of any wizardry or voo doo is there any way I can package the dependent libraries and import them in my script?

Comment: [I'm the maintainer of `xlwt` and author of `xlrd`] Please edit your question (1) to make it very plain that you are using `xlwt` only as an example of a pure-Python package (2) to remove the irrelevant `xlrd` tag.

Comment: @John Machin, @Rnet:  xlwt tag added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `setup.py` typically does with any pure-Python package is copy files into a standard place and compile the `.py` files to `.pyc`. I can't imagine why your employer would regard that as (nasty) third-party software, but the source of the package is OK, your IDE is OK, Python itself is OK, etc ...

Options:

(1) Copy the `xlwt` directory from a source distribution to somewhere that's listed in `sys.path`

(2) Make a ZIP file `xlwt.zip` containing the contents of the `xlwt` directory and copy it to ditto.

(3) As (2) but compile the .py files to .pyc first.

If somebody points out that the above involves error-prone manual steps, you can:

(a) write a script to do that

or

(b) copy `setup.py`, change its name, pretend that you wrote it yourself, use it, ...

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question you should be able to obtain the source archive and simply copy the "xlwt" directory to the same directory as your script and it should be importable from the local directory.